# Finding age of person in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I wish to find out if a person has crossed particular age (in years) in order to make him eligible for some benefits.

---

I posted this question as I was not getting perfect answer when I used DateDiff (using 'YYYY' as interval) function in VB 6.0

I changed the logic and used DateAdd function and then DateDiff. I wrote the following code to  find out exact age.

```
Public Function GetAge(dob As Date) As Integer
    Dim tempDate As Date

    If IsDate(dob) = False Then
        GetAge = -1
    Else
        tempDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 11, dob)
        If DateDiff("d", tempDate, Date) > 0 Then
            tempDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 19, dob)
            If DateDiff("d", tempDate, Date) > 0 Then
                tempDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 25, dob)
                If DateDiff("d", tempDate, Date) > 0 Then
                    GetAge = 3
                Else
                    GetAge = 2
                End If
            Else
                GetAge = 1
            End If
        Else
            GetAge = 0
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Notes:

```
-1 : Error in DOB
 0 : child
 1 : Teens
 2 : Youth
 3 : Senior
```

Comment: Well, this of course depends on your implementation.  Post some code and a particular example, and then see if people can help you out.  As it stands, this isn't even a question.

Comment: In fact, I wanted to post code as answer. I did the same now for others to understand. DateDiff returns simply subtraction result between years of two dates. It is simple code to get difference in years but not correct when DOB is considered as first day of new year.

Comment: Even so, the question as it stands doesn't give others an opportunity to provide a potentially better solution.  It's extraordinarily open-ended and open to interpretation; I would still edit the question to avoid this flurry of downvotes.

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead to modify this question.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with it, it's a perfectly valid question with a fairly simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
if dateserial(year(dob) + 25, month(dob), day(dob)) > now then
```

Comment: Still you have to use DateDiff function. this code simply add numbers to year part of date.

Comment: "I wish to find out if a person has crossed particular age (in years) i" - it doesn't matter what their age is, just that they have crossed it (athat was the question). This code does that.